# Error in Intent Service in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, stack-trace

I am trying to fetch some for Location Address using IntentService but ended up with error leading to app crash. Please help me.

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.ResultReceiver.send(int, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ajender.sample2.FetchAddressIntentService.deliverResultToReceiver(FetchAddressIntentService.java:91)
        at com.example.ajender.sample2.FetchAddressIntentService.onHandleIntent(FetchAddressIntentService.java:81)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is `FetchAddressIntentService`:

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
private static String TAG="Fetch-address-Service";
protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;

/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
public FetchAddressIntentService(String name) {
    super(name);
}
public FetchAddressIntentService(){
    super("FetchAddressIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String errorMessage = "";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(
            Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);
    mReceiver=intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);
    Log.e(TAG,"1-----");
    List<Address> addresses = null;

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(),
                // In this sample, get just a single address.
                1);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        // Catch network or other I/O problems.
        errorMessage = "service_not_available";
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
        // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
        errorMessage = "invalid_lat_long_used";
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                ", Longitude = " +
                location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
    }
    // Handle case where no address was found.
    if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
        if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMessage = "no_address_found";
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        }
        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
    } else {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
        // join them, and send them to the thread.
        for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "address_found");
        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                        addressFragments));
    }

}

private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
    Log.e(TAG, "2-----");
    mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
    Log.e(TAG, "3-----");
}
```

This service should have to send back bundle with Result Receiver and result code but not happening....

Comment: You are trying to call `send()` on a `null` `ResultReceiver`. Beyond that, we cannot really help you, as we cannot see the source to `com.example.ajender.sample2.FetchAddressIntentService`.

Comment: once check .....please @CommonsWare

Comment: `mReceiver=intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);` -- this is not working, in that you are getting `null`, apparently. Make sure that you are filling in this extra.

Answer (score 3):

The error can be resolved following the steps below

- In the MainActivity

  - Add public AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
  - mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(null)- This will automatically assign a id for the main activity class.
- In the FetchAddressIntentService

  - Add mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);
  - Check whether mReceiver is null by logging it.
  - Send the data using your current code.
    It should work. Thats how I got Around it.If you have any problem comment.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you haven't initialize the `mResultReceiver` from your activity correctly, which you are supposed to pass to the `FetchAddressIntentService`  intent:

```
mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new android.os.Handler());
..
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
..
startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens in case of `IntentService` is that you have **three components** that are playing role: `MainActivity` (that will call the intent service), `IntentService` (which is responsible for handling the intent) and the last `ResultReceiver` which receives the result after the intent has been handled (or operated).

As evident from the `Log` you have not initialized or assigned any value to `ResultReceiver mReceiver`
You should initialize mResultReceiver by declaring a class let us call it `AddressResultReceiver` which extends `ResultReceiver` and has a parameterized constructor that accepts a single parameter as `Handler` object and overrides the `onReceiveResult()` method like the following:

```
    AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    //Result from intent service
    @Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle bundle) {
       ...
    }
```

Now you have successfully obtained two of three components: `MainActivity` for starting an intent request and `ResultReceiver` for receiving the result. Let us now make our `IntentService` by defining a class in the project hierarchy and extending it with `IntentService` and overriding its method `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)()`:

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
     public FetchAddressIntentService() {
        super("FetchAddressIntentService");
     }
     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {...}
}
```

So we are now good to go to get the things up and working. Now write the following code in your `MainActivity`:

```
  //Initializing the reference with AddressResultReceiver object
  mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());
  ...
  //Setting the IntentService to FetchAddressIntentService
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

  /*passing the receiver object to the service so as to let it know where to 
    publish results*/
  intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
  ...
  //starting the service
  startService(intent);
```

Now your `deliverResult(int, String)` would no longer throw `NullPointerException`. For more information visit [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and [ResultReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html). Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your protected void onHandleIntent (@Nullable Intent intent){} before Geocoder

```
    if (intent != null){
        String errorMessage ="";
        resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);
        if (location == null) {
            return;
        }
```